# Python Hello World Program Error The script is not executable

Tags: python, apache, ibm-midrange

I am trying to run a simple Python Hello World script. I have the program working through the command line but not when I try to run it from our website. I get a 404 Not found error The script request is not valid. The script is not executable. I am working off an IBM AS400 ISeries under an Apache webserver that is also running PHP.

I added

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

to the httpd.conf file to turn Python on for my server. The file I am running has read and execute permissions. 
I will post my current config file below and here is the code I am trying to run.

```
#!/QOpenSys/usr/bin/python3
print("Content-type: text/html\n");
print("\n\n");
print("<HTML>");
print("<HEAD>");
print("<TITLE>Test</TITLE>");
print("</HEAD>");
print("<BODY>");
print("<H2>Hi there.</h2>");
print("</BODY>");
print("</HTML>");
```

I am still trying to figure out this whole Python thing and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Config:

```
# BMAServer Web Server Configuration created by MCCI/Chuck Mason on 2/13/2019
#LoadModule ibm_ssl_module /QSYS.LIB/QHTTPSVR.LIB/QZSRVSSL.SRVPGM

LoadModule zend_enabler_module /QSYS.LIB/QHTTPSVR.LIB/QZFAST.SRVPGM

Listen *:85

DocumentRoot /www/bmaserver/htdocs
TraceEnable Off

Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%{Cookie}n \"%r\" %t" cookie
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

CustomLog logs/access_log combined
LogMaint logs/access_log 3 0
LogMaint logs/error_log 3 0

ServerName BMAserver

SetEnvIf "User-Agent" "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
SetEnvIf "User-Agent" "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0
SetEnvIf "User-Agent" "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
SetEnvIf "User-Agent" "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
SetEnvIf "User-Agent" "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive
SetEnvIf "User-Agent" "MSIE 4\.0b2;" force-response-1.0

DirectoryIndex menu.php

CgiConvMode %%MIXED/MIXED%%
#TimeOut 30000
KeepAlive Off
HotBackup Off

DefaultFsCCSID 37
CGIJobCCSID 37

AccessFileName .htaccess
AddCharset UTF-8 .htm .html

# zend fastcgi
# Directive name "FastCgiConfig" is not recognized. (argh)
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fastcgi-script .php

RewriteEngine on

<Location *>
  <LimitExcept GET HEAD OPTIONS TRACE POST>
     Order Allow,Deny
     Deny From All
  </LimitExcept>
</Location>

<Location />
  Require valid-user
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName MHBAServer
  PasswdFile %%SYSTEM%%
  UserID %%CLIENT%%
</Location>

<Directory />
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny From all
</Directory>

# Allow requests for files in document root
<Directory /www/bmaserver/htdocs>
  Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .py
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow From all
  AllowOverride all
</Directory>

# Allow requests for OutQueue
<Directory /www/bmaserver/OutQueue>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow From all
</Directory>

AliasMatch ^/htdocs/(.*) /www/bmaserver/htdocs/$1
AliasMatch ^/OutQueue/(.*) /www/bmaserver/OutQueue/$1
```

Comment: Please don't be offended, but it must be asked: Are you *sure* the Python script is in an appropriate directory? And that the directory itself and any parent directories have the proper permissions?

Comment: Oh, is your Python interpreter really `/QOpenSys/usr/bin/python3`? If you've used the recent RPM-based installation (with `yum`) then you want `/QOpenSys/pkgs/bin/python3`. You can check with `which python3` at the command line.

Comment: My python script is in the /www/bmaserver/htdocs directory which also has read/execute permissions and is the directory that is allowing ExecCGI to run. This was installed using IBMs built in PTF and applications install process. When I run the command `which python3` I get the /QOpenSys/usr/bin/python3 directory as a result.